# Double Clicking marker google maps api c# ios

Tags: c#, ios, google-maps, xamarin, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to create a mobile app in xamarin in c# for ios using the google maps api

When you click a marker, the title appears, but when you click it again the title goes away. Is there any way to keep the title from disappearing on the second click?

I want the double click to change the content of the title, but I can't display the info if the title disappears.

Ive been playing around with different combinations of setting mapview.SelectedMarker = marker when I detect a second click on the same marker, but it won't work and I can't find any answers online.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working if anybody is having the same problem.

```
mapView.TappedMarker = (map, marker) => {

//Change the title

mapView.SelectedMarker = null;
return false;
}
```